# Does a Late Bris Necessitate Teffilin?

Tags: tefilin, time, brit-milah

When one makes a Bris after Shacharis, he wears Tefilin. If a Bris is made later on in the day, does he wear Tefilin? Why or why not? And if he does, does it require a second Bracha?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3438/are-tefillin-supposed-to-be-removed-before-a-bris-circumcision-if-so-why

Comment: More specifically, a bris, like counting omer or reading megillah or kiddush, takes place during Shacharis. Customarily we delay alenu till afterwards to include the boy in שלא עשנו כגויי הארצות and additionally we keep the tefillin on till then as well. Places that began performing cucrcumsicions outside the context of davening never brought those prayer rituals along to the new venues

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21829&pgnum=130) is a source that talks about wearing tefilin on bris (in section "בענין הנחת תפילין בעת ברית מילה‬").

As I understand, one should wear tefilin on bris and it doesn't matter if it is a late bris or not.

Answer (score 1):

I've attended afternoon Brises attended by some very respectable rabbis, and no one wore tefilin.

With a normal Bris taking place immediately after Shachris, the practice ([of many](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3438/are-tefillin-supposed-to-be-removed-before-a-bris-circumcision-if-so-why)) is simply to leave them on for a Bris. I see of no reason why one should go out of their way to put tefilin on a second time in a day, which is not our general practice.

As for a second bracha: if there was time in between the wearings that you could not have worn tefilin (such as entering a bathroom), then yes you would need a second bracha.

Comment: The question you link to is about those attending a _b'ris_, whereas this question asks about someone making a _b'ris_.

Comment: @msh210, I see no distinction. I attended an afternoon bris at the shul of a world-class posek (with the rabbi present), done by a very well-established mohel, and no one was wearing tefilin.

Comment: Right: I wasn't objecting to your first paragraph. I was merely pointing out that the link you provided might not be on point: it discusses one issue whereas this question (and the rest of your answer) is about another.

Answer (score 1):

The Shearim Metzuyanim B'Halacha brings a [Machlokes](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14621&st=&pgnum=76) whether one should wear Tefilin at a Bris. The Shach, Magein Avraham, Chida, Taz and others say you should. However the Aters Tzvi and others say you should not. Therefore I do not think it would be necessary to go put them on for a late Bris. It would only be required if you are already wearing them anyway.

Comment: The _SMBH_ is talking about someone attending a _b'ris_, whereas this question asks specifically about someone making a _b'ris_.

Comment: Do any of these sources indicate any distinction between already wearing the tefillin and not? Why would you think that distinction matters at all?